# Paginación a tabla Bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código que me genera una tabla con los registros extraídos desde una base de datos, pero necesito meterle a esa misma tabla una paginación de números ya que cada día van a a ir aumentando esos registros.

He estado leyendo como poder hacerlo pero no me queda lo suficientemente claro. No sé si con una función `Javascript` o algo de `JQuery` podría quedar mejor.

¿Alguna ayuda? Gracias de antemano

```
echo "<div class='container'>";
          echo "<table class='table table-hover table-sm' style='margin: 0 auto; float: none;'>
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Usuario</th>
                    <th>Hora Inicio</th>
                    <th>Hora Inicio Pausa</th>
                    <th>Hora Fin Pausa</th>
                    <th>Hora Final</th>
                    <th>Total Horas</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>";

          $arrayHoras = array();

          $result = mysqli_query($link, "select pk_controlhorario, fk_usuario, hora_inicio, hora_inicio_pausa, hora_fin_pausa, hora_final from control_horario where fk_usuario = 'admin'");

          while ($fecha = $result->fetch_array()) {
              $horas = calculohoras($fecha['hora_inicio'], $fecha['hora_final']);

              $tiempoPausa = calculohoras($fecha['hora_inicio_pausa'], $fecha['hora_fin_pausa']);

              $horasTotales = calculohoras($horas,$tiempoPausa);

              $fecha2 = date('H:i',strtotime($horasTotales));

              array_push($arrayHoras, $fecha2);

              echo "<tr>
                      <td>$fecha[fk_usuario]</td>
                      <td>$fecha[hora_inicio]</td>
                      <td>$fecha[hora_inicio_pausa]</td>
                      <td>$fecha[hora_fin_pausa]</td>
                      <td>$fecha[hora_final]</td>
                      <td>$fecha2</td>
                  </tr>";
          }

          function sumarHoras($introducirArray) {
              $total = 0;
              foreach($introducirArray as $h) {
                $parts = explode(":", $h);
                $total += $parts[1]*60 + $parts[0]*3600;
              }
              return gmdate("H:i", $total);
          }

          $totalHoras = sumarHoras($arrayHoras);
          echo "<tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><b>Total:</b></td>
                    <td>$totalHoras</td>
              </tr>";
          echo "</table>";
        echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con `dataTables` de `Bootstrap` lo puedes lograr. Adicionalmente te ofrece la opción de búsqueda y puedes seleccionar cuantos registros quieres que te muestre por página.

Voy a ponerte un ejemplo con datos fijos y tu solo debes reemplazar la parte del `tbody` con tu código de `PHP`.

No lo hago directamente ya que el `snnipet` arrojaría un error.

El ejemplo es con `Bootstrap 4` pero en `Bootstrap 3` también funciona.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Hora Inicio</th>
                <th>Hora Inicio Pausa</th>
                <th>Hora Fin Pausa</th>
                <th>Hora Final</th>
                <th>Total Horas</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Hora Inicio</th>
                <th>Hora Inicio Pausa</th>
                <th>Hora Fin Pausa</th>
                <th>Hora Final</th>
                <th>Total Horas</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El código `Javascript` lo coloco en un `<script>` en el `head` no?

Comment: Listo! Lo tengo perfecto! Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: ¿Sabes como podría ocultar el `search`?

Comment: Si lo quieres ocultar abre llaves como si fuera un JSON y pon lo siguiente `$('#example').dataTable( {
  "searching": false
} );`

Comment: Hay alguna forma de poner los textos en español?

Comment: @RafaelMonroyRodriguez Por supuesto. En la pagina oficial de `datatables` muestran la forma de hacer la traducción al español, https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/Spanish. puedes crear una plantilla dentro de tu proyecto o hacer la referencia al CDN https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json

Comment: muy útil. Para la aplicación de la tabla con paginación